# Java Comparator - function access

Tags: java, comparator

I have class:

```
public class GridResponse<V> {
    public void setPage(int page) {
        this.page = page;
    } 
}
```

And class implemented Comparator:

```
public class GridComparator<GridResponse> implements Comparator<GridResponse> {
    @Override
    public int compare(GridResponse o1, GridResponse o2) {
        o1.setPage = '1';
        return 0;
    }
}
```

What is wrong in class GridComparator, because I don't have access to function in GridResponse? Why?

Comment: Can you add a code snap what you are trying to do and failing? (showing what exactly you don't have access to). Also - is `GridComparator` an *inner class*?

Comment: Only problem seems from the code you posted is, you are using `non-generic` version of your class, whereas your class `GridResponse` is generic.

Comment: I updated my post, I don't write o1.setPage, because I have: setPage cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: There is no member `page` in `GridResponse`. Also, `o1.setPage = '1';` is not valid Java code as `setPage()` is a method and not a public member...

Comment: @brimborium.. Well, `o1.setPage = '1';`, is a valid Java Code. It's just that, it is not valid here.

Comment: This is a really weird comparator. Why are you changing the state of `o1` in the comparator? And it always returns `0`, so it isn't comparing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The `GridComparator` class should not be generic at all**, it is specific for the `GridResponse` class.

```
public class GridComparator implements Comparator<GridResponse<Integer>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(GridResponse<Integer> o1, GridResponse<Integer> o2) {
        o1.setPage(1);
        return 0;
    }
}
```